# Two channels between two switches

Tags: cisco, switching, etherchannel, gre, ip-forwarding-table

Is there a way to provide two physically diverse channels between two switches? I'm using two Cisco Catalysis 3560s, and I want to have two separate channels between them, with different access control lists enforceable.

I know I can use an EtherChannel to group two or more interfaces together, but I want to have more control over what traffic uses which interface. With EtherChannels, I would have to enforce the same ACL on every interface (not an option for me).

Perhaps there is a solution using GRE Tunnels or manually editing the forwarding table. I'm just wondering if anyone here has experience that could help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: We need a little more clarity on what you're trying to accomplish.  Two VLANs using two different ports?

Comment: With the same VLAN(s), STP will create a _single_ loop-free path. Using etherchannel is simply the way to fool STP into thinking that multiple links are a single link so that STP doesn't disable all but one link, and the switches will not try to send broadcasts, unknown unicasts, and multicasts back on a different link in the channel.

Comment: I'll try to be clearer: I'm trying to have multiple links between two switches, such that I can guarantee isolation of traffic on particular links. Maybe multiple VLANs is the way to do this. VLAN 1 could use interface 1, configured as an access port, and VLAN 2 could use interface 2, also configured as an access port.

Comment: @MattHall This is exactly what MSTP or RPVST+ are for. Look at "VLANs with spanning tree".

Comment: OK. Then I am confused. You could certainly have channels that are access interfaces, but multiple channels would need to have a different VLAN, or channels that are trunk interfaces, but each channel would need a separate set of  non-blocked VLANs. That is something that is done all the time. GRE tunnels and forwarding tables are routing (layer-3), not bridging (layer-2).

Comment: This is the point where you should include a diagram of what you are trying to do, and a better explanation of why you need to do it.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your actual goal, there are several possibilities. Load balancing your flows 'at will' requires them to be split across different VLANs or very delicate fine tuning.

**VLANs with spanning tree**

Using MSTP with multiple instances or RPVST+, you can arrange/configure your VLANs onto both links and then connect the switches redundantly but with dedicated links for each VLAN group. In case of a link failure, the disconnected VLANs can use the remaining link.

To configure, set the links as VLAN trunks and use the same tagging scheme - don't connect yet.

With MSTP, set up two instances and group your VLANs according to the desired distribution. Most simply, use one instance for VLAN 1 and the other for VLAN 2. Configure each link port to use one of the instances. MSTP will build a separate spanning tree for each instance, forwarding only over the desired port (unless the other link fails).

With RPVST+, you configure each VLAN's priority on each port and (pretty much) draw the traffic to that link.

**VLANs without spanning tree**

You could simply connect different VLANs across both links and deactivate spanning tree altogether. Note that there is no loop protection and no failover this way - not really recommended unless you want an simple setup.

**LAG without VLANs**

Setting up a link aggregation group/Etherchannel you'd need to select the port traffic distribution algorithm or change the MAC/IP addresses/port numbers that result in your optimal flow balancing. This may sound the easiest but is actually the hardest to do outside a lab.

We were using this variant for load balancing our Veeam backup streams across both core switches with only gigabit links with LACP - the backup flows use a special subnet with hand-picked IP addresses to optimize the flows.

(This is included for completeness - since your question is about using separate ACLs, LAG won't work as you've already stated.)

Comment: Thank you! Forgive this sort of X/Y follow up question, but do you know if I could use a combination of these? Obviously, I can't have spanning-tree and NOT spanning-tree, but I've thrown out spanning tree already. So is it possible to have a LAG on two interfaces, and a VLAN on a third, between the same two switches? Or two LAGs, with their own ACL parameters?

Comment: You can use multiple LAGs of course, but that doesn't solve your problem of loop prevention and traffic distribution. Multiple logical links *require* VLAN separation or spanning tree. You cannot have multiple active links in the same L2 segment.